# asp.net mvc - changing the default attribute values in a view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, binding, model

I have a view (actually, an editor template) which is used to input each item in a child collection of a parent object.

Pseudo code:

```
public class MyParent {
    public int MyParentID;
    public virtual ICollection<MyChild> Children;
}
```

I have some jQuery that is dynamically is calling a method in the controller and adding my partial view to the DOM.  In order for the model binding to work, the HTML needs to look like this:

```
<input name="Parent[0].PropertyA ... />
```

But the controller always returns this:

```
<input name="PropertyA ... />
```

... and so the model binding fails to bind the child elements into the child collection.

I started down a path of doing some javascript/jQuery manipulation of the returned HTML to manually insert "Parent[0]." into the name attribute.  I could still do that, but it's pretty verbose.

I thought of another idea... views allow you to manipulate the HTML output.  For example, if I put this in my view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(r => r.PropertyA, new { random="myRandomValue"})
```

... it will add a random attribute.  So I tried to do this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(r => r.PropertyA, new { name="Parent[0].PropertyA"})
```

But it won't change the name attribute.  It seems that this overload of HiddenFor will only add additional attributes, but won't change the default attributes.

**My question:** is there a clean way to change the 'name' attribute so that the output will work with the model binding on postback?

Comment: THis isn't an answer (and is in fact self promotion so I expect this comment won't last long), but I wrote this http://formfactory.apphb.com/ instead of EditorTemplates. It handles collections correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following to override the name attribute:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(r => r.PropertyA, new { @Name="Parent[0].PropertyA"})
```

Comment: Yes, this worked!  Strangely, I had already tried @name, and that did not work.  So this result surprises me because the default output of the attribute is "name," not "Name."

Either way, this is working now, thank you much!